# Mock static methods es6 classes to test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, sinon

I have a lib say 'services.js'

```
class Service {
    static doSomething() {
         return Promise.resolve({});
    }
}
```

I have another handler 'handler.js'

```
let Service = require('./Service');
exports.search = (req, res) => {
    Service.doSomething().then(result => {
        res.send(result);
    }).catch(err=>{
       res.status(500).send(err);
    });
}
```

I want to test my handler. To do so I tried stubbing the static method in Service class like:

```
let Service = require(path to services.js),
    Handler = require(path to handler.js),
     http_mocks = require('node-mocks-http'),;

describe("handler tests : ", () => {
    before(()=>{
        sinon.stub(Service, 'doSomething').callsFake(()=>{});
    })
    it('should succeed', (done) => {
        let response = buildResponse();
        let request  = http_mocks.createRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/search?q=2',
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            let result = JSON.parse(response._getData());
             //Some validation
            done();
        });
        Handler.search(request, response);
        done();
    }) 
})
```

I get TypeError: Service.doSomething is not a function. Is there an alternative? I tried using mockery as well. Am I missing something

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in the test code. `Service.doSomething()` returns `promise` but in the test file, we stub it using `callsFake` and it doesn't return `promise`

We might use `resolves` for this as in

```
before(() => {
 sinon.stub(Service, 'doSomething').resolves('asik');
});
```

NOTE: `resolves` has been supported since Sinon 4.

Comment: This didnt help either. I still get Service.doSomething is not a function.

Comment: @randomcoder interesting issue. Let me check again.

Comment: I got it working. Your solution works. Issue was probably with the versions of different packages. I just moved everything to latest and used your suggestion. worked like a breeze